# Multiline grepping – What’s wrong with this expression?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Consider this sample file (line numbers are for reference only):

```
1 Reference duiarneutdigane uditraenturida enudtiar.
2
3 Reference uiae uiaetrtdnsu iatdne uiatrdenu diaren uidtae
4 on line 23.
5
6 uiae
7
8 uaiernd Reference uriadne udtiraeb unledut iaeru uilaedr
9 uiarnde line 234.
```

I was hoping to match every string beginning with “Reference” and ending with a period (i.e. ll. 1, 3–4, and 8–9) using this grep command (tst is the sample file):

`grep -P '(?s)Reference.*?\.' tst`

However, it only matches the first line. What I was thinking:

- `(?s)`, so `.` matches all characters, including newlines
- `.*?` should make the star non-greedy, so it doesn’t match the whole file if it ends with a period.
- The expression should end with a literal period `\.`.

I’ve also tried awk and grep’s `-z` flag, but with both I get either every line or not all lines match my expressions.

Comment: IMHO `pcregrep -M` is more suitable than trying to force `grep` to do multiline matches using `-z`

Comment: This may be the case. I haven’t tested because pcregrep is not installed on my machine by default and I’m reluctant to install new software if I need it in just one tiny script. With vatsug’s help I’ve found a solution that fits my needs.@steeldriver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)Reference.*?\.' tst.txt
```

where `tst.txt` is your input file. It is the same regex as yours, but with two new flags.

I added the `-z` flag to suppress newline at the end of line, substituting it for null character. Thus `grep` knows where end of line is, but sees the input as one big line.

The `-o` flag means that it only prints the matched part.

I got the following output:

```
Reference duiarneutdigane uditraenturida enudtiar.
Reference uiae uiaetrtdnsu iatdne uiatrdenu diaren uidtae
on line 23.
Reference uriadne udtiraeb unledut iaeru uilaedr
uiarnde line 234.
```

Comment: That’s definetly helpful. Thanks! I’m still somewhat unhappy with all linebreaks being gone in the output, though. Is there a way to reinsert them (e.g. at “…line 23.Reference…”), so all occurences of “Reference” start at a new line?

What I get is this:

`Reference duiarneutdigane uditraenturida enudtiar.Reference uiae uiaetrtdnsu iatdne uiatrdenu diaren uidtae`
<newline>
`on line 23.Reference uriadne udtiraeb unledut iaeru uilaedr
uiarnde line 234.`

Comment: @bleistift2, with `-z` the output terminator is also `\0` (the null char); several unix commands alsa have a `-z` to define that input or output is null separated.

Comment: With some more try’n’error I found this really simple solution: `grep -zoP '(?s)Reference.*?\.\n?' tst`. By matching the `\n` at the end of the line, I get line breaks in the output: `Reference duiarneutdigane uditraenturida enudtiar.`<newline>
`Reference uiae uiaetrtdnsu iatdne uiatrdenu diaren uidtae <newline>
on line 23.` <newline>
`Reference uriadne udtiraeb unledut iaeru uilaedr <newline>
uiarnde line 234.` The ending line break needs to be optional, else the last line wouldn’t match, since there is no newline preceding the end of file. Thank you for your help @JJoao and vatsug